# How can I have an object follow the mouse position when a user clicks?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I want an `Image` to pop up when on the location of my cursor when the user clicks down, and vanish when the user releases the mouse button. I tried the `OnMouseDown` function but was unable to get it working. I found `gameObject.SetActive()`, but was unsure of how to use it. I currently am trying to `Destroy` the object when the mouse is released.

```
private void OnMouseDown()
{
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)) 
    {
       Destroy(gameObject);
    }
}
```

Comment: `GameObject.Instantiate`?

Comment: If you want to toggle a gameObject, instead of using `Destroy`, use the `SetActive` as you mentioned. To Disable `gameObject.SetActive(false);` and to Enable `gameObject.SetActive(true);`.

Comment: public GameObject but;

that's all I have....

is there anything else you think?

i did it based on example i found on the web...

i'm confused, i don't know anything else

Comment: yeah but the set active in the if statement doesn't work weather its false or true

why?

Comment: I don't believe OP is looking for `Instantiate`. They do **not** want to `Destroy` this gameObject. It seems they just want to toggle the active state of the object when a user clicks down, or at least that is what I gathered from their question.

Comment: Now the question seems to have totally changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe all you want to do is enable and disable a `GameObject` that follows the mouse when the mouse is held down. If you attach this script to an object that is **not** the object you are enabling/disabling, then drag the reference in to the inspector, it should do what you want.

```
[SerializeField] private Transform objectToMove = null;
[SerializeField] private Camera mainCam = null;

private bool clicking = false;

private void Start()
{
    if (mainCam == null)
        mainCam = Camera.main;

    objectToMove.gameObject.SetActive(false);
}

void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
    {
        objectToMove.gameObject.SetActive(true);
        clicking = true;
    }

    if(Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0))
    {
        objectToMove.gameObject.SetActive(false);
        clicking = false;
    }
}

private void LateUpdate()
{
    if (clicking)
    {
        Vector3 targetPos;
        Vector2 mousePos = Input.mousePosition;
        targetPos = mainCam.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3(Input.mousePosition.x, Input.mousePosition.y, -mainCam.transform.position.z));
        targetPos.z = objectToMove.position.z;
        objectToMove.transform.position = targetPos;
    }
}
```

It will just check in `Update` when the user has clicked and lifted their mouse button. Whenever you click down, the object that you want to be enabled is set to enabled and when you release the mouse, it is disabled.

In `LateUpdate`, if a click was detected in `Update`, then it will continually update the position of your target `GameObject` based on the mouse position screen space converted to world coordinates.

Here is a gif of the above script in action:
[image: Example]

Comment: It doesn't do anything it doesn't appear it stays vanished....

Comment: @RomeoMeier Does your object start as visable? I believe the `z-component` of your position is behind the camera, so it is not being rendered by the camera. The code does work as I tested it and provided a gif of it working. Something else about your setup is not right. Did you child the object like I said? Or put the script on the actual object? I'm guessing you added the script to the object itself, which is wrong. Add the script to some other object that is not the one you want to toggle.

Comment: Thank you a lot!
now it works!

You've been a Big Help!
Thanks

Comment: @RomeoMeier Glad, I could help! If you want to close this question and let others know that it has a working answer, you can do so by clicking on the green arrow to the left of the post.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking For `Instantiate()`.
You can use the overload `Instantiate<Type>(GameObject objectToInstantiate, Vector3 position, Quaternion rotation)`,  and supply the method call with the current mouse position using `Input.mousePosition()` which returns a Vector3.

You might need to convert the mouse position from world to screen or the other way around, depending if your are working with 2D or 3D. You can read about it here:
https://gamedevbeginner.com/how-to-convert-the-mouse-position-to-world-space-in-unity-2d-3d/